# SQL Query Self Join from two tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

I`m stuck on the following problem.
There are two tables:

**banks**

```
bank_id [PK] | name
---------------------
 1            Bank_1
 2            Bank_2
 3            Bank_3
 4            Department_1
 5            Department_2
 6            Department_3
```

**relations**

```
id [PK] | parent_id | filial_id
--------------------------------   
 1         1            5
 2         2            4
 3         2            6
```

Need to select all pairs of Banks-Departments. **Banks without departments should be also selected.**

I wrote following query:

```
SELECT A.name AS 'Bank', B.name  AS 'Department'
FROM banks A,
     banks B 
        JOIN relations ON B.bank_id=relations.filial_id
                      AND A.bank_id = relations.parent_id;
```

But it displays only banks with department. How should I change my query to output string Bank_3 which has not a department??

Comment: Don't mix explicit join with implicit, comma separated joins. Too confusing.

Comment: How do you know that `Bank_3` is a bank and not a department?

Comment: As I understand, alll recording from banks table with id != relations.filial_id are banks.

Comment: I'd say if you are in a position to change the table structure, go for @Tajinder's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do with an union

```
SELECT A.name AS 'Bank', B.name  AS 'Department' 
FROM  relations AS R 
INNER JOIN banks AS A ON A.bank_id = R.parent_id
INNER  JOIN banks AS B ON  B.bank_id=R.filial_id ;

UNION 

select name, null
from banks where bank_id not in (select parent_id from relation)
```

Comment: I already tried it but this query displayes 36 rows - all combinations of Banks-Departments. Not working as needed

Comment: Answer  udpated .

Comment: @Stephen   then bank are joined  by parent_id  .. and is union select are showd  only the bank (parent_id ) not in relation

Comment: @scaisEdge `banks` has both banks and departments, bad design I know.

Comment: @Stephen   i don't know if is a bad design is hierarchical relationship...   but the main table is in relation inner  join  based   for different condition ..

Answer (score 2):

I think your table should be as given below

1. Bank table will only include  **bank_id ,  bank name**. In which **bank_id** will be primary key.
2. There will be separate table for the departments which include **bank_id , dept_id , dept_name**
3. **bank_id** in departments table will be foreign key from **banks** table
4. **dept id** will be primary key in **departments** table

Your banks table will be divided as given below.

```
    bank_id  bank_name
    1            Bank_1
    2            Bank_2
    3            Bank_3

    bank_id dept_id dept_name
       1     4            Department_1
       2     5            Department_2
       2     6            Department_3
```

Then you can simply use left join to get data in required format.

Currently, in your banks table there is no identification column for bank and department.

Comment: Probably the best answer. Bank and department are two different things and putting them in the same table obfuscates and complicates things. Especially with a relations table that invites for numerous possible errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.name AS 'Bank', B.name  AS 'Department' 
FROM (SELECT * FROM banks WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Relations WHERE filial_id = bank_id)) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Relations r 
INNER JOIN banks B ON B.bank_id= r.filial_id ON   A.bank_id = r.parent_id
```

Output:

```
Bank                 Department
-------------------- --------------------
Bank_1               Department_2
Bank_2               Department_1
Bank_2               Department_3
Bank_3               NULL
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need to change `INNER JOIN banks B` to `LEFT`, otherwise it won't return banks that have no departments, despite `LEFT OUTER JOIN Relations`.

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński no you don't. that inner join applies to the left join only

Comment: What DBMS are you testing this on? Seems like in PostgreSQL INNER JOIN that is in relation to LEFT JOIN will make that LEFT JOIN to work just as if it was INNER. In addition to this, your INNER JOIN also relates to subselect A, so I don't really see how it doesn't limit results to only those with departments. EDIT: Oh, it actually doesn't relate to table A, you just put both `ON` conditions by that INNER JOIN. Not sure on what DBMS this query doesn't return syntax errors and gives output as you posted.

Comment: OK, so it seems I have been wrong and you are correct. Never saw such syntax before (double ON with JOIN), but seems to work just as you described.

Comment: @Łukasz Kamiński: You are right. This is invalid SQL. Maybe, maybe *MySQL* accepts that though. It is known for neglecting syntax rules on `ON`. I don't know of any other DBMS having this defect. In any case, even if this query should work in some DBMS it is not readable.

Comment: This works on SQL server. It is more readable in the sense that you can see which table is left joined. `Banks B` is not an optional join in relation to `Relations`

Answer (score 0):

Departments are all "banks" that exists in relations.filial_id. Banks are all "banks" that don't. Use outer joins to get the departments for a bank, so as to also keep banks without departments.

```
select b.name as bank_name, d.name as department_name 
from (select * from banks where bank_id not in (select filial_id from relations) b
left join relations r on r.parent_id = b.bank_id
left join banks d on d.bank_id = r.filial_id
```